# Django Grapelli change background column headers

Tags: django, django-models, django-grappelli

I'm using django grapelli. In my model there is color field which users can select color with colorfield widget. I want to change columns header background color. Does anyone know anything about this? I couldn't found anything.

Comment: Kindly post your code so that we can provide some help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Change Admin color scheme**

In your root "templates" folder create new folder named "admin" create new html file "base_side.html"

Generate a custom color css file using this [CSS_GENERATION_TOOL](https://www.dothedev.com/django-admin-custom-color)

choose your desired colors
generate the css file "django_color.css"
place the file in your static folder

in your base_site.html file add:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n static %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans "Add header name here which is you want to change the color" %}{% endblock %}
{% block extrastyle %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "path/to/generated/django_color.css" %}"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

Note: first generate color which is you want to change. Add that path which is generated.

Hope this may be help you to change the color of header